# How to extract char-sequence after pattern between quotes in Bash?

Tags: bash, sed, grep, substring

I have a property file meant for Java like:

```
oracle {
    username = "bla"
    password = "blabla"
    driver = "driver1"
}

postgres {
    username = "pg"
    password = "pg"
    driver = "pg-driver"
}
```

when read into java I can extract the `oracle.driver` property which returns `driver1`.
Now I want to extract the same string in a bash script. 
I have tried something like:

```
grep -A5 oracle application.conf | grep -Po 'driver = ".*?"' | grep -Po '".*"'
```

returning `"driver1"` (including the quotes). I also tried using `sed substitute` but that also did not yield the `driver1` string.

How can I retriever only `driver1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With single **`awk`** command - will work in ANY **`awk`** implementation:

```
awk '/oracle/{ f=1 }f && $1=="driver"{ gsub(/"/,""); print $3; exit }' file
```

- `/oracle/{ f=1 }` - on encountering line matching the pattern `oracle` - set active flag `f`
- `f && $1=="driver"` - if it's "active" processed section ("oracle") and the 1st field `$1` is equal to `driver`:

  - `gsub(/"/,"")` - remove double quotes from the line
  - `print $3` - print the 3rd field which is the *driver* value
  - `exit` - exit the script execution immediately avoiding redundant processing

---

The output:

```
driver1
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have name -> value mappings in your data, first creating an array to store those mappings (`f[]` below) and then accessing the data by it's name provides the simplest, clearest and easiest to enhance solution:

```
$ awk -v RS= '$1=="oracle"{ for (i=3;i<=NF;i+=3) f[$i]=$(i+2); print f["username"]}' file
"bla"

$ awk -v RS= '$1=="oracle"{ for (i=3;i<=NF;i+=3) f[$i]=$(i+2); print f["password"]}' file
"blabla"

$ awk -v RS= '$1=="oracle"{ for (i=3;i<=NF;i+=3) f[$i]=$(i+2); print f["driver"]}' file
"driver1"

$ awk -v name="driver" -v RS= '$1=="oracle"{ for (i=3;i<=NF;i+=3) f[$i]=$(i+2); print f[name]}' file
"driver1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` you can do this using an empty record separator:

```
awk -v RS= '/^[[:blank:]]*oracle/{
gsub(/.*driver[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*|\n.*$|"/, ""); print}' application.conf

driver1
```

Empty `RS` makes all the continuous non-empty lines a single record.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with sed too

```
database='oracle'
search='driver'
sed -n '
/'"$database"'/!d
:A
n
/'"$search"'/!bA
s/[^"]*"\([^"]*\)"/\1/
p
q
' application.conf
```